# how to make textarea inactive with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

i have such html code and i'm using jQuery:

```
<div><textarea style="height: 150px; width: 250px" name="myName" id="myId" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" > </textarea></div>
```

as for now, i validate this field after submit button is pressed. but how can I inactivate it while typing symbols?
f.e. max amount is 50 symbols and on the 51 symbol it becomes inactive or it in any way disallows user's typing, so the user cannot type more than 50 symbols.
how to implement it with jQuery?
thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No jQuery needed, add the `maxlength` attribute:

```
<textarea maxlength="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: From a code standpoint it's a win.  From a UI standpoint, you just failed because you essentially caused your user a "silent error"

Comment: @bpeterson76 I think most users are familiar with the concept of a field not allowing more than x characters. Of course a js character counter below the textarea would be a nice plus, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: The `maxlength` attribute was only [added to `textarea` in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/textarea), so this isn't reliable in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Monitor the textarea, and whenever a key is pressed, trim the length of its contents:

```
$('textarea').on('keyup',function(e) {
    var clen = 50,
        $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val().length > clen) {
        $this.val($this.val().substr(0,clen));
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/AYUeE/

Since the `maxlength` attribute was only added to textareas in HTML5, you should use a JavaScript-based solution like this in addition to that for maximum reliability.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Limit](http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/)

$('#myId').limit('50,'#charsLeft');